# 2 way binding not working on directive in isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm just trying to do a simple directive, but for some reason the 2 way data binding isn't working in my directive. From my code you can see that a console log in the directive that will read the correct information I have in the *$scope.displayMaintenance* variable, but I can't change it in my directive.

HTML:

```
<maintenance-banner display-maintenance="displayMaintenance"></maintenance-banner>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.displayMaintenance = false;

$scope.$watch('displayMaintenance', function(data) {
  console.log("i changed!: " + data);
});
```

Directive:

```
.directive('maintenanceBanner', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    displayMaintenance: '='
  },
  templateUrl: '/partials/navbar/maintenance-banner.html',
  link: function(scope) {
    console.log(scope.displayMaintenance);
    scope.displayMaintenance = true;
  }
};
})
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you perhaps create a JS Bin or something recreating the problem? I don't see anything here obviously wrong. I usually do my controllers a bit different, but that shouldn't cause issues.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/jalojurewe/1/edit but I can't reproduce the error on JSBin.

Comment: Then the problem must be something other than the logic shown here. The biggest gotchas are usually something being misspelled or using the wrong notation (camelCase instead of dash-case or vice versa). The only thing I can say at this point is to try writing your controller and directive again, keeping things as simple as possible and building more complicated logic in small chunks. That way, if something goes wrong, you'll have a better idea of specifically where it happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue may be that you use your directive inside another isolated scope.

I have created a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/2063n7te/

changing the model value using assignment replaces the model object which may not be reflected in the parent scope.

in short: do not bind primitives directly to the scope.

instead of

```
$scope.text = "foo";
```

use

```
$scope.input = {
  text: "foo"
};
```

a good read is: http://www.thinkingmedia.ca/2015/01/learn-how-to-use-scopes-properly-in-angularjs/
point #4 applies specifically to the behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: This is what I had ended up doing, but can you explain to me why it works sometimes? I have an existing directive in my app right now where I'm running into the same issue, but on about 25% of the pages it's working and it has the same implementation as the ones that don't work.

Comment: There is a difference between isolated scopes and child scopes. When you are acting on a child scope and perform an assignment to the scope, you disconnect the property from a separate parent-scope property. this is ok, as long as you only read the values, but modifying means replacing in that context.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your directive can find the template URL.

Works for me:

```js
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.displayMaintenance = false;

$scope.$watch('displayMaintenance', function(data) {
  alert("i changed!: " + data);
});
});
app.directive('maintenanceBanner', function() {
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  replace: true,
  scope: {
    displayMaintenance: '='
  },
  template: '<div>{{displayMaintenance}}</div>',
  link: function(scope) {
    console.log(scope.displayMaintenance);
    scope.displayMaintenance = true;
  }
};
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  
<maintenance-banner display-maintenance="displayMaintenance"></maintenance-banner>
  </div>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the issue. When I do something like $scope.displayMaintenance.display = false; it seems to resolve the issue. I'm not sure why though. Especially since yours seems to work fine.